# Unity Settings reset after login on Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, theme, settings, unity

I've been using Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) for about 1 month, I've done some small customization like installing the compizconfig to change some stuff and gnome extensions to have Dash-to-Dock and make UI looks nicer, but when I go to the unity settings page and change cursor to another theme it changes on the current session, after startup all the config I make to cursors or icons (launcher and nautilus) are gone.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Found the solution myself, but, it's good to keep here in case someone stumbles upon the same problem, my configuration file was corrupted, to solve it, I had to erase my conf and reboot the system doing the following in a terminal window *CTRL+ALT+T or run from launcher*

```
rm -rf ~/.config/dconf/user
reboot
```

Worked for me and I could change settings and then they got saved at last